# zenity window is not shown when called from `at` command

Tags: bash, notification, zenity

Calling zenity command shows an alert window, as expected:

```
zenity --info --text="test"
```

But calling zenity with `at` does not show the alert window, at the specified time:

```
echo "zenity --info --text=\"test\"" | at 15:00
```

In case of `notify-send` the notification is shown:

```
echo "notify-send \"Reminder\" \"test\"" | at 15:00
```

Why can't I see the alert window when calling zenity from `at`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a display for the output:

```
echo "zenity --info --text=\"test\" --display=:0.0" | at 15:00
```

([via](https://superuser.com/a/327023))

Comment: Correct! Just for ref: `echo "env DISPLAY=:0.0 zenity --info --text=\"test\"" | at 15:00` also works!